# Spring Boot - access component inside a servlet

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application that serves my jersey based api. I have a requirement to have the services layer serve blob data to a client as a stream. I wrote a servlet to do that and configured it as follows.

```
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean(){
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(new BlobReaderServlet(),"/blobReader/*");
    }
```

However, in the servlet code I can't seem to inject any components (they are all null). I need to inject a component that actually loads the blob data from the database.

```
@WebServlet(name = "BlobReaderServlet",
        urlPatterns = {"/blobreader"})
@Component
public class BlobReaderServlet extends HttpServlet {

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

    @Inject
    DocumentLoaderComponent blobLoader;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
```

I strongly suspect the servlet isn't a spring managed component after all and dependency injection isn't working. How can I get access to a component from the context?

UPDATE

It was much simpler than I thought.

```
@Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        ApplicationContext ac = (ApplicationContext) getServletConfig().getServletContext().getAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE);
        this.documentBlob = (DocumentBlob) ac.getBean("documentBlobBean");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that your servlet isn't a Spring managed bean. That is because you are instantiating the instance directly (i.e., calling `new BlobReaderServlet()` in your bean method). Another solution is to change your configuration class as follows:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean(){
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(blobReaderServlet(),"/blobReader/*");
}

@Bean
public BlobReaderServlet blobReaderServlet(){
    return new BlobReaderServlet();
}
```

This will allow Spring to manage the instance and perform autowiring on it.